# not able to connect to redis in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

First thing first, the details:

node version: v16

Using redislabs cloud (v6.2.3)

npm package redis version 4.0.3

Here's the code...

```
const redis = require("redis");
require("dotenv").config();

const client = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_URI,
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD
});

client.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("Connected to our redis instance!");
  client.set("iAmAKey", "Value");
});
```

On running it doesn't output anything :( and just quits simply after some time.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(process.env)` to see if you manage to get them.

Comment: Yep it logs the var correctly.

Comment: `client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));` Any error from this?

Comment: Nope no error :( The client is not connecting to redis ig as stated by Guy Rose. But the weird thing is its not throwing error. I cant find any working example now of node-redis which works with redis labs :/

Comment: This is correct for the behaviour. You can still bind an event to the client even you didn't connect to the redis server and that's why there is no error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I made it work now. Adding this as a reference for any future wanderer with the same issue.

So the community suggested to use URL instead.

```
const redis = require("redis");
require("dotenv").config();

(async () => {
  const client = redis.createClient({
    url: `redis://default:${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}@${process.env.REDIS_URI}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`,
  });

  client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));

  await client.connect();

  await client.set("key", "value");
  console.log("Redis Connected!")
  const value = await client.get("key");
  console.log(value);
})();
```

Here's the issue for future reference: [Not able to connect to redis-labs cloud redis server #1892](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1892)

Comment: What is `require("dotenv").config();` Without dotenv and url it works as well.

Comment: I'm getting `Redis Client Error ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout` error

Answer (score 1):

The call to `.createClient` creates a client but doesn't actually connect to Redis. So the connect event never fires. Node Redis 4.x supports promises so you really don't need the callback at all. You can accomplish the same thing with:

```js
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();

await client.connect();
await client.set('foo', 'bar');
let foo = client.get('foo');
```

Note that I removed the usage of `dotenv` and just have it connect to Redis on `localhost` in my sample code for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

additionnel information to @Amresh this is what worked for me:

```
  url: `redis://${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}@${process.env.REDIS_URI}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`,
```

without ***default*** word.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Node 14 using Redis `^4.3.1`. Changing the version to `^3.1.2` worked for me.